# Comparing values in a many to many relationship in my database

Tags: mysql, database, relationships, erd

I am trying to compare the data in two of my tables which are joined by a composite table as they are a many to many relationship.

I have members and i have centres. Members can attend many centres and a centre can have many members, so i have a composit table in the middle with memberID and CentreId

Now when i try to find all the members that attend centre 1 for example i assumed id do something like this:

```
SELECT members.FirstName
     , centre.CentreLocation 
  From centre JOIN members
 WHERE centre.CentreID = 1
```

This will get me:

```
FirstName  CentreLocation
John       Gladsaxe
Mikkel     Gladsaxe
Kim        Gladsaxe
```

And continue through my entire database getting all the first names and repeating the centre over and over again. Which I assume is its getting all the members and for each member it gets the centre again as the ID is 1, even though not all these members attend this centre.

Am i doing something wrong in terms of my relationship design or is my SQL not specific enough?

Here is a screenshot of my database.
[image]

Comment: There's no relationship here

Comment: I think your composite table should have `id`, `MemberID`, and `CenterID`, field `id` is used as primary key.

Comment: @Ukasyah nope. A surrogate is not useful in this instance

Comment: Remember, it's called Structured Query Language. The clue is in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Table **center** does not have any direct relation to **memberID** (**members** table). The table which links **members** table to **center** table is **memberattendscenter**, which I can't see it in your query. I think you should ***JOIN*** on table **memberattendscenter** in your query .

Moreover, as others said, I think **memberattendscenter** and members tables should have a separate column for primary key.

Comment: As Strawberry commented on the question, there is no benefit to an added memberattendscenter id, since the point of the table is to pair members & centres, and it just introduces opportunities for inconsistencies.